# Ecto validate_required of either of two attributes

Tags: ecto

What's the best way to do a validation of the presence of either of two attributes for a changeset?

The validation should only fail if neither of the two attributes is provided

e.g. consider a User model with attributes :name, :uid, :email, :phone

- :name always needs to be present
- either :email or :uid should be present
- :phone is optional

Would this work?

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
      |> cast(params, [:name,:email,:uid,:phone])
      |> validate_required([:name, :email]) || validate_required([:name, :uid]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may start with something like:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
    |> cast(params, ~w(name email uid phone)a)
    |> validate_required(:name)
    |> validate_required_params(params)
  end
end

def validate_required_params(changeset, %{"uid" => _}) do
  changeset
  |> validate_required(:uid)
end

def validate_required_params(changeset, %{"email" => _}) do
  changeset
  |> validate_required(:email)
end

def validate_required_params(changeset, _params) do
  changeset
  |> add_error(:params, "either :uid or :email is required")
end
```

But you need to also check for example if both `uid` and `email` are provided. What in such case?

Comment: so the parameter map should always contain string keys, and not atoms, correct?  

I'm having difficulty writing my controller test for this. 

`@valid_attrs %{"uid" => "abc123"} `

gives me an error: `** (ArgumentError) expected a keyword list in 'where', got: [{"uid", "abc123"}]`

Comment: it all depends on how you have the rest designed. you can use atoms in your tests because they will be converted in json request

Comment: some equivalent to HashWithIndifferentAccess might be useful